# Chrome dev tools not mapping ts source

Tags: angularjs, typescript, google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools, source-maps

My chrome dev tools suddenly stopped mapping the .ts sources hence causing issues with debugging. When I load a js file I am getting a hint saying "Source Map detected". Further down the message says "Associated files are available via file tree or Ctrl+P". However, i dont see these files in the tree nor by Ctrl+P. For clarity the "Enable Javasript source maps" in the settings is Enabled. Same exactly codeset on another machine working properly. What could be an issue?

Comment: I'm running into the same issue. It did spontaneously resolve for a while without any seemingly related changes, and then it broke again (without any changes related to source maps or webpack).

Comment: In the past, I had some weird issues with chrome too. Did you restart the browser?

Comment: Add your webpack config

Comment: @Raulucco, maybe it was a browser restart that wound up fixing the issue for me.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Debugging Typescript in Visual Studio Code and Chrome](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/jtarquino/2016/01/24/debugging-typescript-in-visual-studio-code-and-chrome/) as a debugging tool with sourceMaps.

Comment: some tool is deprecated there, so I guess this solution doesn't work anymore